# Issue with printing a degree symbol (°) in Swing

Tags: java, macos, swing, unicode

I have a simple program which displays data from a weather station in Swing.  I am using `System.out.print(temp + "\u00B0" + "F");` to display the temperature.  On Windows this displays as "70°F", but on MacOS it shows "70�F". Is there a way to display the degree symbol reliably on all platforms?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream( System.out, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
out.println( temp + "\u00B0" + "C" );
```

(by the way, I took the liberty of fixing your temperature measurement system too.)